# Determine the structure for C6H13Cl using the following data.

Tags: organic-chemistry

The H NMR for C6H13Cl states that there are 3 different types of protons:

6H, triplet
4H, quartet
3H, singlet

What will the structure look like?

Comment: Welcome to ChemistrySE. What are your own efforts to solve this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The molecule you're looking at is 3-chloro-3-methylpentane.

Symmetry causes H NMR to integrate 2x for the 6H and 4H signals.

Comment: Rats!  My cover is blown! +1 for noting the symmetry.

Comment: I was about to draw out this structure but I was overthinking it. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Where was Samantha's effort to solve the NMR problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful hint:  when you have a triplet and a quartet with the area ratio given as above, it indicates the presence of ethyl groups.  Since the total area under those peaks is 10 H, there are two of these  groups equivalent to each other.  Only one isomer with the given formula does that.

Comment: Hoping you could have taken it the rest of the way, but my cover was blown.